# Compose 3 Modal Bottom Sheet not above safe area

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

[image]

Hello guys, so i use ModalBottomSheet from Compose Material 3, and when i show the bottom sheet it appears from the bottom of the screen. What i want to achieve in here is that the bottom sheet should be shown above the safe area (not overlapping with the center "line" like in the picture. Any idea how to achieve this? Thankyou

Comment: Are you using "WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)"? If yes, you have to handle safe areas manually.

Comment: not found in my code @Abhimanyu

Comment: use ```Modifier.navigationBarPadding()```. it will add padding as much as size of navigation bar at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is an issue with the default safe insets when it comes to the `ModalBottomSheet`. The only way I could get this to work was to:

1. Set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in Activity's AndroidManifest.xml entry.
2. Call `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` in Activity.onCreate.
3. Apply safe insets to entire contents of app like this:

   ```
   setContent {
       Box(Modifier.safeDrawingPadding()) {
           // the rest of the app
       }
   }
   ```

See here for more details:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets#insets-setup

Comment: it works for me after setting ModalBottomSheet content within Box(Modifier.safeDrawingPadding()) {
       
    }.
not worked by putting the entire contents of the app in it.